# How can I get a MySQL database to insert a default value if there's an attempt to insert a null value with Python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I've read answers that do something similar but not exactly what I'm looking for, which is: attempting to insert a row with a `NULL` value in a column will result instead in that column's `DEFAULT` value being inserted.

I'm trying to process a large number of inserts in the mySQL Python connector with a large number of column values that I don't want to deal with individually, and none of the typical alternatives work here. Here is a sketch of my code:

```
qry = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (%s, %s, ...)"
row_data_dict = defaultdict(lambda : None, {...})
params = []
for col in [col1, col2, ...]:
    params.append(row_data_dict[col])
cursor.execute(qry, tuple(params))
```

My main problem is that setting `None` as the default in the dictionary results in either `NULL` being inserted or an error if I specify the row as `NOT NULL`. I have a large number of columns that might change in the future so I'd want to avoid setting different 'default' values for different entries if at all possible.

I can't do the typical way of inserting `DEFAULT` by skipping over columns on the insert because while those columns might have the `DEFAULT` value, I can't guarantee it and considering I'm doing a large number of inserts I don't want to change the query string each time I insert depending on if it's default or not.

The other way of inserting `DEFAULT` seems to be to have `DEFAULT` as one of the parameters (e.g. `INSERT INTO table (col1,...) VALUES (DEFAULT,...)`) but in my case setting the default in the dictionary to `'DEFAULT'` results in error (mySQL complains about it being an incorrect integer value on trying to insert into an integer column, making it seem like it's interpreting the default as a string and not a keyword).

This seems like it would be a relatively common use case, so it kind of shocks me that I can't figure out a way to do this. I'd appreciate any way to do this or get around it that I haven't already listed here.

EDIT: All the of the relevant columns are already labeled with a `DEFAULT` value, it doesn't seem to actually replace `NULL` (or python's `None`) when it's inserted.

EDIT 2: The reason why I want to avoid `NULL` so badly is because `NULL != NULL` and I want to have unique rows, so that if there's one row (1, 2, 3, 'Unknown'), INSERT IGNORE'ing a row (1, 2, 3, 'Unknown') won't insert it. With `NULL` you end up with a bunch of copies of the same record because one of the values is unknown.

Comment: Would that be an option to you to specify defaults on python side rather than on mysql side?

Comment: @merrydeath While that is an option and would probably work in a lot of cases, in this case the database might see a lot of changes in the future, so I'm trying to make it so I don't have to take changes in mysql and spend a lot of time implementing them on the python side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `DEFAULT()` function in the `VALUES` list to specify that default value for the column should be used. And you can put this in an `IFNULL()` call so it will be used when the supplied value is `NULL`.

```
qry = """INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ...) 
         VALUES (IFNULL(%s, DEFAULT(col1)), IFNULL(%s, DEFAULT(col2)), ...)"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. What you need to do is in your database add a default value for the column you want to have the default value. When you create your table just use `DEFAULT` and then the value after you create the column in the table, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `yourTable` (`id` INT DEFAULT 0, .....)
```

if you have already created the table and you need to alter the existing column, you would do something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `yourTable` MODIFY `id` INT DEFAULT 0
```

so in your insert statement coming from python, as long as you pass in either `NULL` or `Nothing` for the value of that column then when the row is inserted into your database, the default value will be populated for that column

Another thing to keep in mind is that you have to pass in the proper number of values when you have a default set up for a column. Say you have a table with 3 columns, we'll call them `colA`, `colB` and `colC`.
if you want to insert a row with `colA_value` for `colA`, nothing for `colB` so it will use it's default value and `colC_value` for `colC` then you need to still pass in 3 values that will be used for your insert. If you just passed in `colA_value` and `colC_value`, then `colA` will get `colA_value` and `colB` will get `colC_value` and `colC` will be `null`. you need to pass in values that will be interpreted by MySQL like this:

```
INSERT INTO `yourTable` (`colA`, `colB`, `colC`) 
VALUES
('colA_value', null, 'colC_value')
```

even though you are not passing in anything for `colB` you need to pass a `null` value from your python program by either passing `null` or `None` to MySQL for the value for `colB` in order to get `colB` to be populated with it's default value

if you only pass in 2 values to MySQL to insert a row in your table, the insert statement under the hood will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `yourTable` (`colA`, `colB`, `colC`) 
VALUES
('colA_value', 'colC_value')
```

which would result in `colA` getting set to `colA_value`, `colB` getting set to `colC_value` and `colC` being left as `null`

if you are passing in the right number of values to be inserted into MySQL (that would mean you need to include `null` or `None` for the value to be inserted into the column with the default value) than that is another story. Please let me know if you are passing in the right number of values so I can help you troubleshoot further if needed.

Comment: I have already done this. The default doesn't seem to actually replace the null value.

Comment: @JohnDoe I just added additional information to my answer, check it out and if it still doesn't help let me know

Comment: The passing in of values to the MySQL query is automated, so it has the right number of values (I also checked manually). I pass in ```None``` for the columns I want to be ```DEFAULT```, like you said, but that just results in ```null``` being inserted, or an error if the column is specified as ```NOT NULL```.

Comment: @JohnDoe and you have the string `DEFAULT` set up as the default value for your column in MySQL itself?

Comment: No, I have stuff like ```col1 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'Unknown' ``` if the column is string type, ```DEFAULT 0``` if it's integer, etc. What I meant by passing DEFAULT as a parameter is that something like ```INSERT INTO table (col1,...) VALUES (DEFAULT,...)``` apparently results in col1 taking on the default value, but I don't know how to do this through python because passing in DEFAULT as a string in cursor.execute results in it being interpreted as a string, not a keyword.

Comment: @JohnDoe that's fine, as long as you actually have a default string set up in mysql itself. Next I would test to make sure that MySQL is actually respecting the default value by running an `INSERT` statement directly in MySQL that should insert the default value in your column. If that works, then I would look into setting up the query log built into MySQL which keeps track of the queries that are run and then try to do the insert from your program. That way, you can then look and actually see how MySQL is putting the `INSERT` statement together based off of your input from your program

Comment: here's the documentation to set up the query log: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html

Comment: @JohnDoe so, instead of setting up your query like `INSERT INTO table (col1,...) VALUES (DEFAULT,...)` have you tried setting it up like this: `INSERT INTO table (col1,...) VALUES ('',...)` using two single quotes with nothing between them instead of the string `DEFAULT`?

Comment: I tried that, it just literally interprets that as a string with nothing in it. Barmar's answer seems to do what I'm looking for.